# NestJS application with firebase-admin fails when deploying to google app engine flex

Tags: google-app-engine, nestjs, firebase-admin, google-flexible

I am able to deploy to a standard app service, but when I try to deploy to my flexible environment, I receive this error:

```
Step #1: /app/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/app/firebase-namespace.js:84
Step #1:         this.INTERNAL = new FirebaseNamespaceInternals(appStore ?? new lifecycle_1.AppStore());
```

Google turned up some results for that error and they were about the nodejs version not jiving with the version of firebase-admin.  Initially, I was seeing the same problem on my standard environment so I made the change in my package.json to update to version 16 and included `runtime: nodejs16` in my app.yaml for the standard environment.  That fixed my deployment issue for the standard environment.  My flex environment is still showing the same error.  I have updated my app.yaml for my flex environment to this:

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex

runtime_config:
  runtime_version: 16
```

but still seeing the same error.

any ideas of other things I should try to resolve this issue?

TIA

Comment: Please let me know if the information below was helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/runtime#node_versions),

> Specifying a Node.js version in your application's package.json file
> by using the engines field.
>
> ```
> {
>    "engines": {
>      "node": "18.x"
>    }
>  }
> ```
>
> The engines.node property can be a semver range. If you specify this,
> the runtime downloads and installs the latest version of Node.js that
> matches the semver range. If no match is found, the application will
> fail to deploy and the runtime will return an error message.

You need to make sure you have updated the node version in the
`package.json` file along with the `app.yaml` file as you already
mentioned.

In case you have already updated the node version in the `package.json` file as well, then you need to check with the `firebase toolset version`. Check whether you are using the latest version of firebase toolset. If not you need to update the firebase toolset to the latest version by using the command

`sudo npm install -g firebase-tools@latest --force`

Also make sure that --force shouldn't be used unless you want to really replace the existing toolset.

Comment: I didn't mention in my OP but I have set the engines.node property to 16 and rebuilt to update packagelock also.

Comment: If you have already updated the node version in the package.json file, Then as I mentioned you need to check with the firebase admin version. Whether it is supported with your node.js version or not. If not please try to update the firebase admin version.